# Custom CSS for Bootstrap not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap to build a website, and I want to have an image appear as grayscale until I hover over it, at which point it should become full color.

Instead of editing the Bootstrap.css, I created my own custom css: 'starter-template.css'.
Here's the code in 'starter-template.css':

```
.thumbnail2 {
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
z-index: -9999999999999999999999999px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
}

.thumbnail2:hover {
-webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
z-index: -9999999999999999999999999px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
}
```

And here's the html:

```
<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="static/starter-template.css" type = "text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

....

```
<a href="{{my_link}}"><img class = "thumbnail2" src="{{my_string}}"  align="right" height = "200" width = "200"></a>
```

However, there is no hover effect--the image appears as full color when the page loads and doesn't change when I hover over it.  Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: z-index doesn't have a unit, so remove the `px` from those rules. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Comment: Which browser are you using for testing? -webkit-filter applies only for chrome and safari. Also I don't see how bootstrap is related to this question. Is it possible to create a fiddle just to check that the code you have posted here works or not?

Comment: I am using Chrome. I deleted the px, but that had no effect :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think fixing your z-index is all you need: http://jsfiddle.net/c8wtbjfw/

```
.thumbnail2 {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    z-index: -9999999999999999999999999;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
}
.thumbnail2:hover {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    z-index: -9999999999999999999999999;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
}
```

Seems to work when I test it in Chrome (36.0.1985.143). Since that's a Webkit filter, it won't work in IE or Gecko-based browsers.

An alternative might be to transition the `opacity` rule, since that has [better support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-opacity). Here's the same CSS, but with opacity instead: http://jsfiddle.net/c8wtbjfw/1/

```
.thumbnail2 {
    opacity: .5;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
}
.thumbnail2:hover {
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
}
```

I did remove your `z-index`, since I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish by pushing the image "under" the rest of the page.

Comment: Thanks.  Weirdly enough, when I saved the custom css under another name, it worked.

Comment: Sounds like a cache issue. A hard refresh or clearing your history would probably have worked as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.thumbnail2 {
    filter: url(filters.svg#grayscale); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
    filter: gray; /* IE5+ */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Webkit Nightlies & Chrome Canary */
    z-index: -9999999999999999999999999;
-webkit-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
}

.thumbnail2:hover {
    filter: none;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
    z-index: -9999999999999999999999999;
-webkit-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
}
```